# Reference binding and the copy constructor/move constructor

Tags: c++

If I have a function like so:

```
int foo(std::vector<int>* integer1ArrayIn, * integer2ArrayIn) {
    std::vector<int>& integer1Array = *integer1ArrayIn;
    std::vector<int>& integer2Array = *integer2ArrayIn;
}
```

1. Will the reference `integer1Array` be calling a copy constructor/move constructor to copy over the elements of the passed in parameter?
2. Does binding a reference to a dereferenced pointer call the copy constructor?
3. In what circumstances does reference binding invoke a copy constructor?
4. Can someone explain what happens as this code executes in memory?

Thank you

Comment: There are no copies involved in your code snippet.

Comment: `integer2ArrayIn` needs a type :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No.
2. No, but it would crash badly if it was nullptr. Consider passing by reference whenever a parameter HAS to be there, and pass by pointer when a parameter MIGHT be there (but always verify for nullptr too!).
3. Whenever the l-value (in this case `integer1Array` and `integer2Array`) are pointers or references, it will never call copy/move constructor.

if you had `std::vector integer1Array = *integer1ArrayIn` it would effectively make a copy.

You can use Jonas's answer to play around with and see for yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

1) No, there are no copies made. You can test it with a small program, like [this](http://ideone.com/D2yssX).

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    foo() { std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl; }  
    foo(const foo&) { std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl; }
    foo& operator=(const foo&) { std::cout << "Copy assignment operator" << std::endl; }    
};

int main() {
    foo* A = new foo;
    foo& B = *A;
    delete A;
}
```

2) Beware of `nullptr`s! Otherwise all is fine.

3) Never (see answer by AlexG)

4) Not sure what you mean by "code executes in memory", since code is not executed *in* memory. If you mean what happens to the memory when the program is executed, then that's another story